# How to get this alignment in data table using visualforce

Tags: visualforce, datatable

[image]

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-SEEnodgzeVs/US9RGSi44WI/AAAAAAAAABE/JNQVlPF6HRk/s1600/SortablePageBlockTable.png

By using which tags i can get this type of layout in Data table salesforce

Answer (score 1):

The basics require an  component which you can find the details of [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm).

To get the pagination have a look at the article [here on DeveloperForce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Paginating_Data_for_Force.com_Applications) to help you solve that issue if needed.